# Error parsing dataorg.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json

I work in a android app which should show the details of a virtual database(WAMPSERVER i use) and make new documents. When i push the button of show details the app displays the above error.The following is the allproductsactivity.java file.I have see and other similar post but i can't understand and solve my problem. I put x.x.x.x:80 on IP address for security reasons.

AllProductsActivity.java

```
package com.panos.appphpconnect;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {




private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jParser=new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://x.x.x.x:80/connect/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_CLASSES = "classes";
private static final String TAG_PID = "_id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "username";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.allproducts);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String _id = ((ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.id)).getAdapter().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EditProductActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, _id);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    if(pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing()){
        pDialog.cancel();
    }
}



/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON response
        Log.d("All products:",json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CLASSES);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

The code of get_all_products.php is the following

```
<?php

/*
* Following code will list all the products
*/

// array for json response
$response = array();


// include db connect class
require("db_connect.php");

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from classes table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM classes") or die(mysql_error());



// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["classes"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $classes = array();
    $classes["_id"] = $row["_id"];
    $classes["username"] = $row["username"];
    $classes["password"] = $row["password"];


    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["classes"], $classes);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing panos response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No submissions found";

// echo no users json
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Also when i run the file get_all_products.php on my browser displays me the error " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION in C:\wamp\www\connect\db_connect.php on line 6" but i don't understand which is line 6 and what is the error.The code of db_connect.php file is the below.

```
 <?php
 //A class file to connect to database

 class DB_CONNECT{

  function_constructor(){

   $db = new DB_CONNECT();

  //connecting to database

  $this->connect();
  }

  function_destruct(){
  //closing db connection
  $this->close();
  }

  //Function to connect with database
  function connect(){
           //import database connection variables
           require_once_DIR_ . '/db_config.php';
           //connecting to mysql db
  $con=mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
  //selecting database
  $db=mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());
  //returning connrction cursor
  return $con;
  }
  //function close to db connection
  function close(){
           //closing db connection
           mysql_close();
           }
           }
           ?>
```

That's all errors of logocat

```
  E/JSON Parser(2234): Error parsing dataorg.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type     java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
  W/dalvikvm(2234): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4e1e908)
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234):   at com.panos.appphpconnect.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:141)
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234):   at com.panos.appphpconnect.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
  E/AndroidRuntime(2234):   ... 4 more
```

Comment: The response that you're getting from your webserver is invalid. Can you post the reponse ?

Comment: line 6 should be 'function_constructor', you're missing a space between function and _constructor. another thing is why are you instantiating a DB_CONNECT object inside the class constructor?

Comment: @lelloman i use the "$db=new DB_CONNECT" to connect with the database. Is this wrong? now i put the correctly spaces and show me the message "No Database Select"

Comment: debug DB_DATABASE constant before mysql_select_db and see if it has right value.
to find the problem always debug all of your variables and results of functions by echo. and check which one is not right.

Comment: @user3636948 you definitely have PHP errors on your website. Please go to the URL of your PHP script in your browser and fix the errors.

Comment: Your web service is sending back HTML where your java expects some JSON, I would first check what your url is returning with a browser and move my way up to the php.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT *FROM classes` is invalid syntax and when you query you should pass the connection to `mysql_query`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classes", $db) or die(mysql_error());
```

And forget about android now, get this to work in your browser then you can worry about parsing it in your app.

Comment: I fix the problem on PHP file eventually. Now when i run the php file in the browser send me back the results, but the error of application persist.